# Mixed content with traeffik 2.0.2

Tags: traefik

i have a little problem of mixed content with traefik, i have read tons of answers everywhere during few weeks but can't fix this last error. its very hard to understand how this work for me. but basically i can't turn on env = prod because it generate error 500 here in there.

the problem appear in easyAdmin when i try to insert something, i got error 500, then if i turn env = dev it works but i got mixed content.

```
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
  - traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
  - traefik.http.routers.xxxx-https.rule=Host(`mysite.fr`)
  - traefik.http.routers.xxxx-https.tls=true
  - traefik.http.routers.xxxx-https.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.frameDeny=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.SslRedirect=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.AccessControlAllowMethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.AccessControlAllowOrigin=origin-list-or-null
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.AccessControlMaxAge=100
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.AddVaryHeader=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.BrowserXssFilter=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.ContentTypeNosniff=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.ForceSTSHeader=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.STSPreload=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.ContentSecurityPolicy=default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.ReferrerPolicy=same-origin
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.FeaturePolicy="vibrate 'self'"
  - traefik.http.middlewares.SslHeader.headers.STSSeconds=31536000
networks:
  - web

traefik:
restart: always
image: traefik:v2.0.2
command:
  #- --log.level=DEBUG
  - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
  - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
  - --providers.docker=true
  #- --api
  - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=my@email.com
  - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt.json
  - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
labels:
  #- "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
  # global redirect to https
  - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.entrypoints=web"
  - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.middlewares=https_redirect"
  # middleware redirect
  #- "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
volumes:
  - ../../letsencrypt.json:/letsencrypt.json
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
networks:
  - web
```

I'm sure it's not much to fix, but i start to bang my head on the wall.
thank you for your time.

**UPDATE :**
Long short story... i didn't know docker keep in memory older generation of docker image...
So, modification works but you have to be careful about your docker cache,
So delete it every time you wanna change something.
Then all your recent modifications will now apply when launching docker-compose.

Good luck.

Comment: Can you elucidate your problem. What do you mean by mixed content and where are your trying to using env=prod?

Comment: hi by mixed content i mean that i have http running with also https. so i try to do a correct redirect for all http request without having http left running. also i try to run env= prod for the entirety of the project.

Comment: it seems that i don't have the correct permissions for apache server. it may be why i can write in DEV but not in PROD for symfony project. unfortunately i call apache from a dockerFile, i will have to check how to do it there. Maybe it's doable in docker compose ?